# SSIS If sequence container is set to TransactionOption = Required data flow task fails

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008, ssis

I have an SSIS data package with a sequence container(and a nested sequence container) that works fine when I set the transaction option to supported.  However when I set it to required it fails. I suspect it's because my source destination is on another server, is transaction option required not a possibility when doing a cross server data flow?

Comment: The error it generates is ...

Comment: [OLE DB Source [1]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "SingleSource" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.

Answer (score 0):

SSIS Is compatible with Transactions across different data sources, however as I understand it they require the use of the MSDTC service. If your data source is not compatible with this then it will fail. If your data source is compatible I.E. another Windows machine with SQL Server, then check that the service is switched on and configured correctly.

You could also set the specific parts of the sequence container to set the TransactionOption to not support to get around it, although I don't know if that will work for a source.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this in the past. ensure you have port TCP port 135(RPC) and program MsDtsSrvr.exe allowed through your windows firewall on the server. you can test by temp disabling windows firewall on the server and run your SSIS package. If it runs enable again and add the rules above.

Hope this helps